# Is it possible to filter by "DATE or OTHER DATE" in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data source that has four different dates associated with each matter- open date, close date, created date, and modified date. I want a scorecard to display the total number of matters that we "worked with" in a set date range, which includes matters that any of those dates are in the correct range for.

I essentially want this:

```
SELECT COUNTUNIQUE(ID)
WHERE ((openDate >= Date1 AND openDate <= Date2) 
OR (closeDate >= Date1 AND closeDate <= Date2) 
OR (createdDate >= Date1 AND createdDate <= Date2) 
OR (pendingDate >= date Date1 AND pendingDate <= Date2))
```

Date1 and Date2 should be selected by the viewer in a control.

I have a control that filters by one of the dates, but I'm struggling to find a way to combine all 4 dates using an "OR" operator. I've tried using filters, metrics, and parameters but I haven't been able to get any working properly. Is there a way I can apply a SQL query similar to the one above to a scorecard?

Any ideas/advise is much appreciated!! I'm new to Data Studio so still getting a feel for how it all works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the data source is Big Query, a custom query can be used and use in the where statement `@DS_START_DATE` and `@DS_END_DATE`.

Otherwise you need to blend the data with itself for each case.
[image]

Use the `id` to join the data set together. Use for each case the data field and add a metric `id_1` , `id_2` ... with the formula `1`.

Then add a chart and a metric field:

[image]

```
case 
when id_1 is not null then id    
when id_2 is not null then id 
else null end
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!!